# Multiple instances of the same Springboot application but only 1 instance consumes messages from ActiveMQ queue

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am running multiple instances of the same Spring Boot 2.0.4 Application, for scaling purposes, that consume messages from an ActiveMQ queue using the following:
@JmsListener(destination = "myQ")

Only the first consumer receives messages and if I stop the first consumer the second instance starts receiving the messages. I want each consumer to consume a message, not the same message, in a round robin fashion. But only the first consumer consumes messages.

Comment: then what did you expect. It is suppose to behave like that. Only if you have a topic then the message will be delivered to all consumers

Comment: Yes, I only want a message to be delivered to a single consumer, but I want both consumers to consume from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a JMS Topic rather than a Queue.  You should also research durable subscriptions, shared subscriptions, and durable topics before you settle on the configuration you need for your setup.

See:

- [JMS API Programming Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-concepts003.htm)  (Search for JMS Message Consumers)
- [Queues vs Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)
- [Durable Queues and Topics](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html)

Comment: I want each message consumed by a single consumer AND I want more than 1 consumer consuming from the queue.

Comment: ActiveMQ defaults to round robin for queues as far as I can tell.  It may be that your prefetch setting is too high for the number of messages that are being sent.  In such a case all messages are still processed by a single consumer because the first consumer reads all the messages from the queue leaving none for the next consumer.  See http://activemq.apache.org/dispatch-policies.html

Comment: thanks, but I have added 5000 messages and can see the queue has messages remaining as the single consumer processes the messages, whilst the second consumer, another instance of the same consumer, doesn't consume any messages.